# Return one folder backwards

Tags: php, directory

I have a dynamic URL, for example:

```
"up/some_images/profile_image_15/200.png"
```

Is there a command that can give me the path:

```
"up/some_images/"
```

?

Answer (score 3):

Yes, use [`dirname()`](http://php.net/dirname)

```
$path = "up/some_images/profile_image_15/200.png"
$grandparentdir = dirname(dirname($path)); // "up/some_images"
```

If you want the trailing `/` you will have to add it yourself.

Answer (score 1):

Try this  [**dirname**](https://www.php.net/dirname)  — Returns parent directory's path

```
<?php
print_r(pathinfo(pathinfo("up/some_images/profile_image_15/200.png")["dirname"])["dirname"]);
```